# Sqoop Import MySql Db failed

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I'll try to import mysql table into sqoop but i am facing the below exceptions,
MySql running in my local machine table creation and db creation working fine, when I'll try sqoop import the job automatically failed.
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

```
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:702)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

        1 file(s) moved.

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 9009
```

Installed MySQL in local machine and added the environmental variables in the system path

Comment: What are you trying to import with, an SQL dump? have a look at [This page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqoop/sqoop_import.htm) and see if it helps you.

Comment: I'll tried to import tables into hdfs and export hdfs to MySql. But i'll face problem while in import.

Comment: 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file, so read the documentation on sqoop

Comment: you need to give the full path till bin of the mysql installation directory.like <mysql_installation_path>/MySql

Comment: In sqoop version 1.4.5 import and export both working fine, now i am updated to 1.4.6 and i'll face this issue.@KSNidhin MySql path is correct, no issues with the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs due to the MySQL Environmental variables added in the system path.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\ ;` The `&` skips the remaing paths so MySQL consider as command line, replace '&' instead of any other characters it's working.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, remove the direct option. Please provide the full command